# Very Simple Explanation of glOrthof() in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I saw some previous posts and explantations on the internet of glOrthof, but I just don't get it. I am watching the Stanford OpenGL ES lesson on Youtube and the following code came up:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0, backingWidth, 0, backingHeight, -1, 1);
```

This code draws a picture 1px by 1px in the bottom left hand corner of the screen. Why would it do this though? I thought this code would take the picture from (0,0) and stretch it across the entire screen because it specifies the plane as from 0 to the width of the screen and 0 to the height of the screen. Can someone please explain as simply as possible why it draws it as 1px by 1px in the bottom left hand corner. The full source code can be found on the Stanford website labeled as "openGLtransforms.zip":

[Source Code Website](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/79)

(The file where this code appears is ES1Renderer.m)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, glortho "maps" what is inside those into your screen, making the center of screen be the center of those planes. So if you place an object at (0,0,0) given your glortho call, the object will be placed at the corner of your scene. Probably is more useful to make the planes go from -backingWidth/2 to +backingWidth/2 and -backingHeight/2 to backingHeight/2. How big is your object? your zFar plane is too close to zNear, do your objects fit into that space?

Comment: My point it is still valid, the " I thought this code would take the picture from (0,0) and stretch it across the entire screen " is not correct. It "maps" what it is inside those plane and make it fit into the screen. You need to place those planes so that what you render between them goes into screen space. How is your GL_VIEWPORT setup?

Comment: I still don't get it :( . What would this do for example:     glOrthof(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);

Comment: Think of Ortho as a cube you're allowed to draw in.  You can draw outside the cube, but that won't show up onscreen.  So, for your question, you would only see polygons in the cube from (-2, -2, -1) to (2, 2, 1).  Since these are 2D polygons, and the Z is set to 0, your Z bounds are negligible.